# Future with State monad

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scalaz

I would like to use State monad to implement caching for data provided from third party API. Let's imagine method `getThirdPartyData(key: String)` which firstly checks cache then if it's not present there should make request to API. First and most naive implementation which came to my mind was enclosing State type within Future -

```
Future[State[Cache, ThirdPartyData]]
```

But it's not correct because when request fails you will lose your cache (`getThirdPartyData` will return `Failure`).

Second option which came to my mind was to extend, or rather redefine State monad - `s => Future[(s,a)]`, instead of `s => (s,a)`, but I thought that it's quite popular problem so `scalaz` probably has some already defined way to solve this issue.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `S => Future[(S, A)]` is what you get with `StateT[Future, S, A]`, but it won't have the behavior you want—one failed lookup will crash the computation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for `StateT[Future, Cache, ThirdPartyData]`?

```
implicit val m: Monoid[ThirdPartyData] = ...
val startState: Cache = ...
val l: List[StateT[Future, Cache, ThirdPartyData]] = ...

val result = l.sequenceU
 .map { _.foldMap (identity)) }
 .eval (startState)
```